# Copying data from one database table into another database table.

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two databases in my project, one is shipped with the .apk and one is build upon the user interaction. Now on the first run I want to copy some data from the shipped DB to the internal DB. I have the following snippet of code:

```
if(personalities !=null && personalities.moveToFirst()){
                        dbHelper.open();
                        do{
                            String name = personalities.getString(personalities.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")); 
                            String displayBirthday = personalities.getString(personalities.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DOB")); 
                            String imagePath = personalities.getString(personalities.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri")); 
                            //      System.out.println("Ext Db Name: "+B+" DOB: "+C+" and imageUri: "+D); 



                            insertAdhocCase(name,displayBirthday,imagePath, "Person", "0", FRIEND_NAME);


                            insertInDb(name,displayBirthday,imagePath, "Person","0", FRIEND_NAME );




                        }while(personalities.moveToNext());

                    }
```

However I am getting the following error: (That is even after opening the connection to db -- dbHelper.open(); )

```
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.exa.digitalanniversaries/databases/Bdr
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1437)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at com.exa.digitalanniversaries.DBAdapter.insertAdhoc(DBAdapter.java:393)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at com.exa.digitalanniversaries.TheWizardOfOz.insertAdhocCase(TheWizardOfOz.java:738)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at com.exa.digitalanniversaries.TheWizardOfOz$AsyncActivity.doInBackground(TheWizardOfOz.java:644)
06-04 11:27:04.897: E/AndroidRuntime(7094):     at com.exa.digitalanniversaries.TheWizardOfOz$AsyncActivity.doInBackground(TheWizardOfOz.java:1)
```

What would be the proper way to do it? Why does it give me this specific error even when I am opening the DB before the transaction?

Comment: I think you should check if database is not already opened before `dbHelper.open();`. If it is not opened, then only open database.

Comment: When I first encountered the problem I was not using dbHelper.open(). Although its worth to give a shot to your suggestion.

Comment: or You can try not closing your database before the above code and then try either by placing `dbHelper.open();` or by removing it in turns.

Comment: The stack trace shows that the problem occurs inside `insertAdhocCase`/`insertAdhoc`. Show how that code manages its database object.

Comment: I am very surprised, when I put an iterating count on the loop, I could see that the loop executes (Doing what is intended for it to do). Now the problem shifted to outside the loop where it encounters another DB insert, over there when I put a dbHelper.open() statement all works fine.

Comment: I am only opening the database object in the onCreate for both the databases. I am not performing open or close anywhere else except for in the onDestroy, where I close them both. (This was the state before I put dbHelper.open() as mentioned in the above comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are not missing anything from these:

- Create two different connections to the two different Databases.
- Select data row by row from DB1
- Insert data row by row to DB2
- When done copying from DB1 (close the connection)
- When done inserting to DB2 (close the connection)

Comment: Nice tips there, I will double check on these!

Answer (score -2):

Close your database (`dbHelper.close()`) at the end of `do..while` statement and it should work fine. Good luck!

UPDATE:
Additionally you can use `dbHelper.isOpen()` method before opening the database to ensure you don't get error.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object` It clearly states that you are trying to reopen a closed database. So search for places where you might have attempted to open closed database.

Comment: I put an iterating count inside the do - while loop and to my surprise, the loop iterates several times copying data. The problem arises once it is out of the loop. However I am trying to find out where -- Log cat is indifferent to my issue.

Answer (score -2):

In the constructor of DBHelper class, check if the user database exists and if not, copy the contents to user database from the apk bundle. Please find a sample code below.

```
/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param context
 *            Context to be used
 */
public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/database/"
            + DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mContext = context;

    if (!checkDataBaseExistence())
        copyDB();

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite
 * .SQLiteDatabase)
 */
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

private boolean checkDataBaseExistence() {

    // database to be verified
    SQLiteDatabase dbToBeVerified = null;

    try {
        // get database path
        String dbPath = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/database/" + DB_NAME;

        // DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // try to open the database
        dbToBeVerified = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // do nothing since the database does not exist
    }

    // in case it exists, close it
    if (dbToBeVerified != null) {
        // close DB
        dbToBeVerified.close();

    }

    // in case there is a DB entity, the DB exists
    return dbToBeVerified != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDB() {

    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;

    try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        myInput = mContext.getAssets().open("database/" + DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/database");
        file.mkdirs();

        String outFileName = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/database/" + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle your exception here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle your exception here
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle your exception here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have both the databases ready at the time of data transfer, I have implemented a different check for that. I dont see that the above is a solution to my problem.

Comment: Then, whenever the user database is created first, you have to copy data from apk bundle database to user database. For this, first store the apk bundle database somewhere on device, then get the data from that and store to user database. After this, you can delete the apk bundle database from device if it is no longer required.

Comment: What? How can you delete the DB supplied with an apk? In my opinion it always remains there in your assets folder! If it is in the assets folder, replication is neither helpful for me nor for the user(If its more than one copy inside the private folder of my app under Databases folder). Plus my question is entirely different from what you are trying to explain!

Comment: I am not saying you can delete the db supplied with apk. If you want to read the table data of that db and copy it to user database, you can copy it to a location on the device and open it using class SQLiteDatabase's openDatabase method. Later if you dont want this db on device, you can delete the file.

Comment: That all is already done, I am using a much better way to load data from this database which is shipped along the .apk. Refer to [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)